# What can I do about `MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (0)?

Tags: swift, scenekit

Upon initialization of my scene, **on rare occasions** the app will crash with this error

> com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer (18): signal SIGABRT

The following is printed in the console

> -[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:]:1097: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (0).'

Lastly, here is the function which is called before the crash

```
func setupRandomScene() {
            self.scene.rootNode.childNodes.forEach({ (node) in
                node.removeFromParentNode()
            })

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if !Model.shared.hasSeenTooltips {
                    self.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/levels/level\(0).scn")!
                } else {
                    switch Model.shared.level {
                    case 1...10:
                        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...8)
                        self.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/levels/level\(randomInt).scn")!

                    case 11...20:
                        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...16)
                        self.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/levels/level\(randomInt).scn")!
                    default:
                        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 9...40)
                        self.scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/levels/level\(randomInt).scn")!

                    }
                }

                let randomColorInt = Int.random(in: 1...4)


                switch randomColorInt {
                case 1:
                    self.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/bg/purple")
                case 2:
                    self.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/bg/pink")
                case 3:
                    self.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/bg/orange")
                case 4:
                    self.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/bg/teal")
                case 5:
                    self.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/bg/cyan")
                default:
                    self.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/bg/blue")
                }

                self.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "road", recursively: true)?.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
                self.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "finishPlatform", recursively: true)?.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

                self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.cameraNode)
                self.scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
                self.scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(0, -9.8, 0)
                self.playerNode = SCNNode()
                self.setupPlayerNode()
                self.setupSounds()
                self.dancingAnimation = SCNAnimation(named: "art.scnassets/stickman/dance\(Int.random(in: 1...10)).scnanim")
                let directionalLight = SCNNode()
                directionalLight.name = "directional"
                directionalLight.position = SCNVector3(-10, 50, -100)
                directionalLight.light = SCNLight()
                directionalLight.light?.type = .directional
                directionalLight.light?.castsShadow = true
                directionalLight.light?.shadowRadius = 2 // 1000
                directionalLight.light?.shadowSampleCount = 20 // 20
                directionalLight.light?.shadowMapSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 2000)
                directionalLight.light?.intensity = 2000
                directionalLight.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, -toRadians(angle: 150), -toRadians(angle: 60))
                self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(directionalLight)
                let ambientLight = SCNNode()
                ambientLight.name = "ambient"
                ambientLight.light = SCNLight()
                ambientLight.light?.castsShadow = false
                ambientLight.light?.type = .ambient
                ambientLight.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
                ambientLight.light?.intensity = 5000
                self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLight)
                self.cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(self.playerNode.position.x, self.playerNode.position.y + 5, self.playerNode.position.z - 9)
                self.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-toRadians(angle: 5), -toRadians(angle: 180), 0)
                self.cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
                self.gameState = .menu
                self.scnView = nil
                self.scnView = self.view as? SCNView
                if let _ = self.scnView {
                    self.scnView!.delegate = self
                    self.overlayScene = OverlayScene(with: self.overlaySceneSize, isLive: self.broadcastController.isBroadcasting)
                    self.scnView!.overlaySKScene = self.overlayScene
                    self.scnView!.present(self.scene, with: .fade(with: .white, duration: 1), incomingPointOfView: nil, completionHandler: nil)
                }

                if !Model.shared.soundIsMuted {
                    self.playerNode.runAction(self.playWooshSound)
                }

                self.positiveHaptic.prepare()
            }
    }
```

Comment: Which line of this function is the one where the error occurs?

Comment: @user1118321 It does not point to a specific line, I just know that this method gets called when the user dies/completes a level and that is the only time the app will crash. It should also be noted that this happens only every 10-15 rounds.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @mnuages Unfortunately, I don't. I will try to reproduce the issue and edit my post to update the logs.